# Force oracle sql developer to show timestamp

Tags: oracle, date, timestamp, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to SQL developer but each time i get queries it changes time stamp to readable date format, but i want my result to be in time stamps as they are in database.

Answer (score 2):

Please go to: Tools/Preferences/Database/NLS and set there date format and timestamp format to what you want.

Oracle stores date and timestamp type but display it according to NLS settings. You either call `alter session set NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FF';` or just set those NLS settings in your client tool.

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_commands_1029.htm#OLADM780)

Comment: i do but i want oracle to display me timestamp and not date format, what should i change at NLS section?

Comment: If column you are displaying is type `date` format displayed is controlled by `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` if column type is `timestamp` it is controlled by `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`. I've also edited answer and added you link to available syntax. @SinaNouri

Comment: @SinaNouri If that not works for you please edit your question and add description of table your query is based on and desired output format.

Comment: @SinaNouri - The date is "stored" in a format you will not understand. If you want to see what is in fact "stored", you can run this quick statement: `select sysdate, dump(sysdate) from dual`. `DUMP()` shows what is stored. Now: If you want a query to show something in a specific format, every time and on everyone's machine, then don't include `col1` in your select, if `col1` is date data type. Instead, include `to_char(col1, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')`. Then what you will see will not depend on NLS_DATE_FORMAT settings. Same with timestamps.